# Need to Decryptor tool the Ransomware .Vesad extension

Tags: antivirus

Need  Decryptor tool for my encrypted jpeg files which was infected by Ransomware .Vesad extension.please help me on this.

Comment: The only reliable thing after a virus attack is restore from a safe backup. And no matter what you do, remember to reformat the affected compuuter as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The **STOPDecrypter** does support some of the .vesad version of this ransomware.

For the software and instructions/details check out the support topic over at Bleeping Computers: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/671473/stop-ransomware-stop-puma-djvu-promo-drume-help-support-topic/